# Challenge: Aggregate Second Element from Input Element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Here's a challenge for MongoDB that I found interesting.

Given a timestamped collection `events` and a specific input selector `_object`, how can we aggregate a list of `event` documents that *followed* the input?

For example, a Schema in Mongoose:

```
var EventSchema = new Schema({
    _object:   { type: ObjectId }
  , timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

An example collection:

```
[
    { _id: ObjectId('1'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...1', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 21 2014 16:30:01 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('2'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...2', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 22 2014 16:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('3'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...1', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 23 2014 16:30:01 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('4'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...3', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 24 2014 16:30:01 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('5'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...1', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 25 2014 16:30:01 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('6'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...4', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 26 2014 16:30:02 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('7'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...1', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 27 2014 16:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('8'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...3', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 28 2014 16:30:01 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('9'),  _object: ObjectId('124abc...1', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 29 2014 16:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('10'), _object: ObjectId('124abc...2', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 30 2014 16:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
]
```

Let's say our intended target is `ObjectId('123abc...1')`.  We'd query our collection using our special method, providing an argument of sequence number `1` (as opposed to `0`, the element itself):

```
Events.mySpecialMethod( { _object: ObjectId('123abc...1') } , 1 ).exec(function(err, output) {
  console.log(output); // contains intended results (see below)
});
```

The intended output of such a query is:

```
[
    { _id: ObjectId('2'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...2', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 22 2014 16:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('4'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...3', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 24 2014 16:30:01 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('6'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...4', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 26 2014 16:30:02 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
  , { _id: ObjectId('8'),  _object: ObjectId('123abc...3', timestamp: 'Sat Jun 28 2014 16:30:01 GMT-0400 (EDT) ) }
]
```

In this case, selecting the *first* element of our intended resultset is easy:

```
Event.find({ _object: ObjectId('123abc...1' }).limit(2).exec(function(err, events) {
  // select the _second_ element of our result set
  console.log(events[1];);
});
```

...but how can we aggregate a list of the 2nd elements given an input `_object`, which may have many entries?

**Bonus:** can we select the *n*th element?

Comment: what are you using as your implicit order?  limit(2) without a sort doesn't guarantee that it will return what you want.  you list documents in _id order - is that the order you expect?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky in this case, only the date implicit in the `_id` field.  To be more accurate, the intent is to use the `timestamp` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is really the best usage of something like this, but what you seem to want some way of skipping over every single cursor result. Really that is probably what you should be doing, even though that does of course mean actually retrieving all of the results even though you are discarding the ones you don't want.

If you really are insistent on trying to make the server do this, then a possible approach can be using the JavaScript evaluation of mapReduce to do this for you.

Consider the sample:

```js
{ _id: 1, oth: "A", grp: "A" },
{ _id: 2, oth: "B", grp: "A" },
{ _id: 3, oth: "C", grp: "A" },
{ _id: 4, oth: "D", grp: "A" },
{ _id: 5, oth: "E", grp: "B" },
{ _id: 6, oth: "F", grp: "B" },
{ _id: 7, oth: "G", grp: "B" },
{ _id: 8, oth: "H", grp: "B" }
```

In order to get every second or `nth` item you are basically working a modulo:

```js
db.sequence.mapReduce(
    function () {
        counter++;
        var id = this._id;
        delete this._id;
        if ( counter % seq == 0 )
          emit( id, this );
    },
    function() {}, // blank mapper
    {
        "scope": { "counter": 0, "seq": 2 },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

Gives you results like this:

```js
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : { "oth" : "B", "grp" : "A"  } },
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : { "oth" : "D", "grp" : "A"  } },
{ "_id" : 6, "value" : { "oth" : "F", "grp" : "B"  } },
{ "_id" : 8, "value" : { "oth" : "H", "grp" : "B"  } }
```

If you wanted that from a starting position query then you can just issue a query section with that

```js
db.sequence.mapReduce(
    function () {
        counter++;
        var id = this._id;
        delete this._id;
        if ( counter % seq == 0 )
          emit( id, this );
    },
    function() {}, // blank mapper
    {
        "query": { "oth": "B" },
        "scope": { "counter": 0, "seq": 2 },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

And then you are just working from that position:

```js
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : { "oth" : "C", "grp" : "A" } },
{ "_id" : 5, "value" : { "oth" : "E", "grp" : "B" } },
{ "_id" : 7, "value" : { "oth" : "G", "grp" : "B" } }
```

Map-reduce always sorts results by the `_id` key emitted. This is by design as the intent is to make sure things are "reduced" in order. But you can play with that value in order to affect your results, and you can also "sort" the input as well:

```js
db.sequence.mapReduce(
    function () {
        counter++;
        var id = this._id;
        delete this._id;
        if ( counter % seq == 0 )
          emit( -id, this );
    },
    function() {}, // blank mapper
    {
        "sort": { "oth": -1 },
        "scope": { "counter": 0, "seq": 2 },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

So counting backwards and sorting the output by making the emitted key a negative value:

```js
{ "_id" : -7, "value" : { "oth" : "G", "grp" : "B" } },
{ "_id" : -5, "value" : { "oth" : "E", "grp" : "B" } },
{ "_id" : -3, "value" : { "oth" : "C", "grp" : "A" } },
{ "_id" : -1, "value" : { "oth" : "A", "grp" : "A" } }
```

In order to otherwise "skip" out to a selective point, then you can change the logic

```js
db.sequence.mapReduce(
    function () {
        counter++;
        var id = this._id;
        delete this._id;
        if ( counter % seq == 0 )
            seen++;

        if ( seen == skip && counter % seq == 0 )
            emit( id, this );
    },
    function() {}, // blank mapper
    {
        "scope": { "counter": 0, "seq": 2, "seen": 0, "skip": 3 },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

That would bring the 3rd sequence of two:

```js
{ "_id" : 6, "value" : { "oth" : "F", "grp" : "B"  } }
```

Remember that all of this "scans" all results that would be valid to the input query, so you are only really "skipping" the cursor on the server side rather than on the client.

Comment: Great answer!  I'm going to leave it open for a while to see if there are any other proposals (maybe that don't use MapReduce?).

Comment: @martindale Just to explain the mapReduce usage, the purpose is to introduce a sequential counter that will respond to the required modulo operation to do this. Unless there is some natural field in your data that would respond to this "every `n` records" requirement then there is no other way to do so. You could do something like the  last value on the timestamp every minute or so, but that is not the same `n` record skipping that you seem to be asking. For instance, the aggregation framework could not introduce this sequence.